# Can HyperLinkButton in silverlight navigate a NAS or Local-file uri?

Tags: silverlight, hyperlink

In my silverlight application I have a section like this:

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding MediaFile.FileName}" 
 TargetName="_blank" 
 NavigateUri="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource MediaFileToFullPathConverter}}" 
 Style="{StaticResource HyperLinkButtonStyle}"/>
```

For testing purposes I use local navigation paths to the ui (C:\blabla\file.txt). In my real world scenario I will provide NAS links (\PcX\file.txt).

However when I click on the C:\blabla\file.txt I get an UnauthorizedAccessException error.
When the link is url it is invoked perfectly (opening a window and loading a page as a harm).
Finally, when I write C:\blabla\file.txt in browser's address bar, the file is accessed perfectly.

Is silverlight so much isolated that it cannot trigger a new window with the address of a local file?

Do you have any clue?

Thx, 
Aggelos

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go with "yes it is", but it looks like you might be able to work around it with the EnableNavigation property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton(VS.95).aspx?ppud=4
(look at the Note)